# bootstrap-wysihtml5 can't get it work:no iframe, no html

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I can't run [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) editor on my page,this my html tag:

```
<h3 class='sectname'>Message</h3>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
        <div class='span12'>
            <textarea name='message' id='message' rows="5" placeholder='Your Message'> </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have included the css and the js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $siteurl.'/min/?g=css_m&amp;5259487' ?>"/>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="<?php echo $siteurl.'/min/?g=js_i&amp;5259487' ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<?php echo $siteurl.'/min/?g=js_m&amp;5259487' ?>"></script>
```

I'm using minify, these are the files:

```
'css_m' => array('//css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css'),
'js_i' => array('//js/jquery-1.10.2.js','//js/bootstrap.min.js','//js/noty/jquery.noty.js','//js/noty/layouts/top.js','//js/noty/themes/default.js','//js/jquery.nimble.loader.js'),
'js_m' => array('//js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js','//js/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js'),
```

Finally I initialize it:

```
$("#message").wysihtml5();
```

But however I can't get it work

Comment: Have you tried double checking your external scripts and styles?

Comment: Yes, minify doesn't return any error

Comment: Actually I checked the plugin. It has form before the textarea please see [here](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/blob/master/examples/simple.html)

Comment: Actually here is the setup , see the documentation [here](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: But if you check the use of the plugin that I have linked it says this under Usage: `<textarea id="some-textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#some-textarea').wysihtml5();
</script>`

Comment: Also I have checked the generated html with the inspector and it generates the toolbar, but it looks like it can't interact with the textarea.

Comment: I have also tried to add the form, but nothing changes

Comment: have you tried putting `<script>$("#message").wysihtml5(); </script>` before `</body>` ends?

Comment: The script tag that contains all the javascript of the page is before the body tag

Comment: it is on `$(document).ready(function()) ?`

Comment: try changing your jquery file `jquery-1.10.2.js` to `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` maybe this is the minimum requirement for the plugin

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.js is the latest version...

Comment: Okay try doing to this.. Go [here](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) , view source then follow the structure. I really do notice that their script is before the body tag ends. I hope it can help you now

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have given up :)